# Unable to uninstall Chromium from Ubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management, chromium

I am unable to uninstall Chromium browser from Ubuntu 18.04.3.
I tried to uninstall it through Ubuntu software and also through commands but didn't work in my case

Command I used:

```
sudo apt-get remove chromium --purge
```

Output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'chromium' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 1):

The app name is wrong. It is `chromium-browser`

```
sudo apt remove chromium-browser --purge
```

Comment: the format `sudo apt purge chromium-browser` can also be used